# "Automatic color" = "no color" for empty point data in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, colors, ssrs-2012, linechart, is-empty

I have a report in which I have some charts containing empty values. I want empty values to be shown as 0, which seems to work, when I set the empty line color equal to "Black" 
[image: Design view of empty color = "Black"]
[image: Chart with empty color = "Black"]

but the line color in the chart becomes see-through ("No Color") when I choose "Automatic color" instead of matching the color to the existing line.

[image]
[image]

Could you please help me understand why this is and how to fix it?
I want the chart to look like the one with black lines, but where the line colors match the existing lines instead of being black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future Reference: worked around this issue by emulating the color palette in the `Color` expression of the series `EmptyPoint` like this:

```
=Choose(RunningValue(Fields!Year.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing), "#01b8aa", "#374649", "#fd625e")
```

**Note**: in this example `Fields!Year.Value` is the "Series Group", the colors in the `Choose` expression are the first three of the `Pacific` color palette.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I no longer work in the same company, so I cannot validate your reply.
Since you are the only to reply I will still accept your answer as the most helpfull.